# How do I bulk change admin user passwords on my SonicWALL?

Tags: sonicwall

I need to frequently bulk change administrator passwords as well as local admin users for over 30 SonicWALLS throughout my organization. Is there an easy way to do this either via GMS or the CLI?

The other thought was maybe an LDAP server for users, and keeping the SonicWALL administrator password for each SonicWALL extremely limited.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You could use RADIUS or TACACS to authenticate instead. Then you just change it once.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Take the language that you prefer and write some script, eg, python, and install dependencies needed for ssh or telnet connections, this is your choice.

1. Firts at all you need to put the  sequences of commands on the exactly way as you will do it  manually. Begin from nothing, connection entablishment, authentication and then the pass change steps.
2. Test it
3. If works, then create some kind of array were you can put all your IP address.
4. Once you get that, write your new PASS into the code, create a repetitive structure, a loop, and put your code into it.
5. Then execute it

Answer (score 1):

Use TACACS+ for admin access to your networking devices.  That's the tool for the job.  However, those brand of firewalls may not support it.  I did find a RADIUS setup guide.  https://support.sonicwall.com/kb/sw6958

Other than using that, just create a batch script (windows):

http://www.howtogeek.com/263177/how-to-write-a-batch-script-on-windows/

> Do you know how to use the Command Prompt? If you do, you can write a
>   batch file. In its simplest form, a batch file (or batch script) is a
>   list of several commands that are executed when you double-click the
>   file. Batch files go all the way back to DOS, but still work on modern
>   versions of Windows.
>
> PowerShell scripts and Bash scripts may be more powerful, but batch
>   files can still be plenty useful if you need to run basic Windows
>   commands.